# Couchbase on the cheap on AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, couchbase

I'm trying to find a way to run Couchbase Server cheaply on AWS but the problem I'm having is that Couchbase is memory intensive and memory on AWS runs a bit of a premium. What I'd like to be able to do is run an Medium EC2 instance (price point wise this feels ok) for my development environment. There are very few documents currently and write speed is VERY low. Yet it appears even with this configuration I'm getting timeouts and errors.

Has anyone cracked this nut?

Comment: Oh, I meant to say an EC2 Small instance, not medium.

Comment: Set up multiple EBS volumes and software RAID them, or configure provisioned IOPS volumes to assist with write speed issues.

Comment: I run spot instances on my production Couchbase server. We use m2.xlarge instances with 17 gb of RAM. 99% of the time we pay $.035 per hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use AWS as our staging/development environment, we found that the small instances were just too underpowered for any useful work.  We use 2 m1.medium instances, both with couchbase running on and one with nginx and a java application server.  It works fine for us allowing 4-5 client machines to work with the environment with no problems or timeouts.

For on your box development I'd recommend spinning up some vm's and having a local cluster for testing.

http://www.irahul.com/2012/09/running-multiple-couchbase-servers-on.html

Comment: Yeah for dev environment I've been operating with just a single node but have been meaning to find the time to switch to a local cluster. I use VMWare but same difference.

Comment: Just out of interest, do you spin up and down your AWS instance through any sort of automated scripts? I suspect this is quite easy but I haven't gotten into the habit and if I could ensure that the Medium instances were spun down during period of non-use then the cost would be far more tolerable.

Comment: Personally we just keep the nodes running all the time, but it wouldn't be hard to automate.  You could follow something like this for the application side https://learnchef.opscode.com/starter-use-cases/multi-node-ec2/